# String Palindrome with stack and queue (C++)

Tags: c++

This compiles fine and works well with no spaces, but once I put spaces in it either tells me its not a palindrome or times out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
int main( )
{
   queue<char> q;
   stack<char> s;
   string the_string;
   int mismatches = 0;
   cout << "Enter a line and I will see if it's a palindrome:" << endl;
   cin  >> the_string;

   int i = 0;
   while (cin.peek() != '\n')
   {
       cin >> the_string[i];
       if (isalpha(the_string[i]))
       {
          q.push(toupper(the_string[i]));
          s.push(toupper(the_string[i]));
       }
       i++;
   }

   while ((!q.empty()) && (!s.empty()))
   {
      if (q.front() != s.top())
          ++mismatches;

        q.pop();
        s.pop();
   }

   if (mismatches == 0)
       cout << "This is a palindrome" << endl;
   else
       cout << "This is not a palindrome" << endl;

   system("pause");
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `cin >> the_string` does not read a line as your prompt would suggest.

Comment: Why such a complicated solution? You can do a palindrome check without a stack or a queue. You can also do it without any extra space requirements.

Comment: @user93353 I think the OP is doing his homework, and using a stack and a queue is a requirement.

Comment: Yes, homework is the reason, thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated?

You could simply do:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

bool is_palindrome(std::string const& s)
{
  return std::equal(s.begin(), s.begin()+s.length()/2, s.rbegin());
}
```

Comment: While I'd agree that this would be a nice approach, you do need to strip out spaces to be equivalent to what his algorithm is attempting.

Comment: This is more appropriate as a comment to the question (and already exists as a comment) than as an answer, since it doesn't fit within the constraint of the question.

Comment: Yes, as Burhan said, it is a homework problem ;) Thanks for the input though guys, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the line

```
cin >> the_string;
```

does not get a whole line. Use this instead

```
getline(cin, the_string);
```

Secondly, while debugging your algorithm print lots of information out. For example, if you add the line

```
cout << "You entered: '" << the_string << "'" << endl;
```

you can easily see what string you're actually testing.

Comment: He is reading in two places. Before the loop with `cin >> the_string;` he read the first work the user type, then in the loop, with `cin >> the_string[i];` he read char by char. Note that if the user input "str1 str2_longer_than_str1" it will overflow the_string, since it sill be holding "str2_longer_than_str1" while its size only fit "str1".

Comment: Thank you, and fbafelipe was right, i removed the first cin >> the_string; and used getline(cin, the_string); and it worked great, thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

I got this solution to work just fine.

```
int main( )
{
    queue<char> q;
    stack<char> s;
    string the_string;
    int mismatches = 0;

    cout << "Enter a line and I will see if it's a palindrome:" << endl;
    int i = 0;

    while (cin.peek() != '\n')
    {
        cin >> the_string[i];
        if (isalpha(the_string[i]))
        {
            q.push(toupper(the_string[i]));
            s.push(toupper(the_string[i]));
    }
    i++;
    }

    while ((!q.empty()) && (!s.empty()))
    {
        if (q.front() != s.top())
            ++mismatches;

        q.pop();
        s.pop();
    }

if (mismatches == 0)
    cout << "This is a palindrome" << endl;
else
    cout << "This is not a palindrome" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void main()
{
    queue<char> q;
    stack<char> s;
    char letter;
    int mismatches = 0;


    cout << "Enter a word and I will see if it's a palindrome:" << endl;
    cin >> letter;
    q.push(letter);
    s.push(letter);

    int i = 0;
    while (cin.peek() != '\n')
    {
        cin >> letter;
        if (isalpha(letter))
        {
            q.push(letter);
            s.push(letter);
        }
        i++;
    }

    while ((!q.empty()) && (!s.empty()))
    {
        if (q.front() != s.top())
            ++mismatches;

        q.pop();
        s.pop();
    }

    if (mismatches == 0)
    {
        cout << "This is a palindrome" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "This is not a palindrome" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Homework done!" << endl;
    cout << "You are Welcome!" << endl;
    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: Please explain what you have changed and why